# Display the same UI element in 2 different windows simultaneously

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, inkcanvas, multiscreen

I'm writing a multi screen store application (which means that i control two windows from my application).
In the first screen i have an InkCanvas - which the user can draw, and i want the second screen to display the same draw - means: when the user draw it appears on both screens.
I tried to create a singletone InkCanvas and add it to the window grid on initilizeComponent, but it fails to add on the second screen with the following exception:

```
The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread.
```

Do you have any idea how can i solve it or maybe another creative way to solve such issue?

Thanks

Comment: If you do not need interactivity for the second InkCanvas, you could use a [VisualBrush](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualbrush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: The second inkCanvas is static - it's sould only dispaly the same content, and it not even use an InkCanvas. Do you have an example of how to use VisaulBrush for such case?

Comment: @PhilipAtanassov I'm using store app, which does not support VisualBrush